# How to learn variable time interval events with lstm

Tags: time-series, deep-learning, classification, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm a little bit confusing about how to format my model for **variable time interval events classification** with lstm.

I'm trying to classify events in time dimension. The events occur with different intervals (e.g., Event1 and Event2 have interval of 3 seconds, Event2 and Event3 have interval of 1.68 seconds). Each event has same number of features to describe its characteristics.

The confusing part is, **the intervals between these events are also critical for the classification problem**. For example:

1) if Event1 and Event2 both have feature x = 0, and the interval is less than 1 second, these series of events would be classified as class 1;

2) if Event1, Event2 and Event3 all have feature x = 1, and the intervals are longer than 2 seconds, these series of events would be classified as class 2.

[image: The sketch of the problem is here]

I searched a lot of questions related to rnn time series problems and found nothing healpful. So anyone has good suggestions on formatting my data and model to deal with this problem?

Comment: Have you considered somehow encoding the interval as an event itself?